# How to check frequent visitors for Age Verification cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a jqueryUI dialog box that asks if the user is 21 years old and sets a cookie for a year.  I want to check each visitor for the cookie so they don't have to verify they are over 21 every time they visit the site. I have found some other age verification code repositories but they are all overly complex. I have downloaded js.cookie.js for the operations.  I'm hoping there is a very simple way to handle it. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance! Here is my code:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Must Be 21 Years Old to Enter">Are you 21 years old?</div>

<script>
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog ({ 
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 410
   });

   $("#dialog").dialog ({
       dialogClass: "no-close",
     buttons: {
       'Yes, I am 21 years old!': function() {
           document.cookie = "ageConfirm=true; expires=365";
           $("#dialog").dialog("close");
       },
       'No, I am not 21 years old.': function() {
           document.cookie = "ageConfirm=";
           window.location.href = "http://www.google.com",
           $("#dialog").dialog("close");
       }
     }
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mr. Smith's suggestion I was able to come up with the answer using an IF statment:

```
if (Cookies.get('ageConfirm') == null) {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog ({ 
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 410
    });
}

else {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog ({ 
        autoOpen: false
    });
}

$("#dialog").dialog ({
    dialogClass: "no-close",
  buttons: {
    'Yes, I am 21 years old!': function() {
        document.cookie = "ageConfirm=true; max-age=31536000";
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    },
    'No, I am not 21 years old.': function() {
        document.cookie = "ageConfirm=";
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com",
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
```

Now the jqueryUI dialog box only shows up if the cookie has not already been set from prior age verification... Yayyyyyy!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog ({ 
            autoOpen: Cookies.get('ageConfirm') === "true",
            width: 410
});
```

The idea is if the ageConfirm cookie is set to true, then don't open the dialog box.  I'm guessing that's what autoOpen does in your code?

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for something exactly like that.  Unfortunately, I believe Cookies.get('ageConfirm') just returns the value which is 'true'.  Since the value is true if you have been to the site already it still opens the dialog box.  It would need to be some sort of If statement I believe. Like if there is no cookie then auto open like you suggested.  I am not very good with javascript so I'm hoping someone knows the exact syntax.

Comment: Adjusted the answer, I think this would work as it checks the string value of the cookie for "true".

Comment: I tried it for shits and giggles.  It did not work my friend.

Comment: Worth a shot 